# Пагинация кастомных постов используя get_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь сделать пагинацию с помощью встроенной функции the_posts_pagination(); Но она не работает в моем примере

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'numberposts'      => 5,
    'category_name'    => 'banket-menu',
    'post_type'        => 'restaurant_menu',
  );

  $posts = get_posts($args);

  foreach( $posts as $post ) {
      setup_postdata($post); ?>

      <div>
          <?php the_field('title_food') ?>
          <?php the_field('price_food') ?>
      </div>
   <?php }
       wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
   <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
```

Comment: Пересохраните структуру постоянных ссылок в админке.

Comment: Постоянные ссылки настрое вот так site.com/%category%/%postname%/, а пагинация не работает

Comment: После создания кастомного типа поста надо один раз зайти в админку на страницу настроек и просто сохранить структуру постоянных ссылок.